# how to overlay geom_rect and geom_boxplot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use `ggplot` in order to overlay `geom_rect` under some boxplots.
I want the grey rectangle will be behind the box plots but I can't do it for some reason.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = reorder(genotype, -Shann.div, FUN = median), y = Shann.div)) + 
  geom_jitter(color="black", size=0.3, alpha=0.9) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, coef = 0) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = avg, color="red") + 
  #geom_hline(yintercept = (avg + 2 * SE), linetype='dashed', color="black") + 
  #geom_hline(yintercept = (avg - 2 * SE), linetype='dashed', color="black") + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=0, xmax=Inf, ymin=avg - SD, ymax=avg + SD), fill="grey", alpha=0.01) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  ggtitle('Microbial UTO - Shannon diversity median') + xlab('genotype')
```

[image]

Comment: Place the `geom_rect()` line before the other geoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ggplot` package draws the `geom` layers in the order that you declare them. If you want the `geom_rect` layer in the back, put it before the other layers in the code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = reorder(genotype, -Shann.div, FUN = median), y = Shann.div)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=0, xmax=Inf, ymin=avg - SD, ymax=avg + SD), fill="grey", alpha=0.01) +
  geom_jitter(color="black", size=0.3, alpha=0.9) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, coef = 0) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = avg, color="red") + 
  #geom_hline(yintercept = (avg + 2 * SE), linetype='dashed', color="black") + 
  #geom_hline(yintercept = (avg - 2 * SE), linetype='dashed', color="black") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  ggtitle('Microbial UTO - Shannon diversity median') + xlab('genotype')
```